# Installing matplotlib vn 1.2 and Basemap on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, matplotlib, apt-get, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to install vn 1.2 of Matplotlib on my Ubuntu computer so that I can use some of the animation features. Crucially I also need Basemap.

The only way I've found of importing Basemap is through apt-get. I can install matplotlib 1.2 loads of different ways - using pip, apt-get and from source, but no matter what I do, when it comes to typing in

```
sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

I'm always told that matplotlib will be installed because apt-get can't see the version 1.2 that I already have.

I've also tried installing Basemap from source (using the instructions on this wonderful website:http://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/) but I'm running into GEOS-related problems that I have no idea how to start solving. If I can use apt-get for installing Basemap then I'd be very happy.

Thank you

Comment: I wrote the tutorial you referenced. I don't have a quick answer to this question, but I will be updating that tutorial in the near future. When I do that, I will take a look at this issue.

Comment: I updated the tutorial [here](http://introtopython.org/visualization_earthquakes.html), so you might see if the updated installation instructions work for you. If they don't, please post a comment here and I will troubleshoot the process with you.

Comment: See [How can I install Basemap in Python 3 / Matplotlib 2 on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46560591/562769)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev

sudo pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git  # latest Version from Source 1.2
```

Older Version might not be compatible with the matplotlib.