# How can I install Basemap in Python 3 / Matplotlib 2 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu-16.04, matplotlib-basemap

I tried

```
pip3 install basemap
```

but [Basemap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/) seems not to be on PyPI.

There is [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18386132/562769) but it has no answer.

### What I did

1. I downloaded basemap 1.07 ([source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/))
2. Matplotlib 2, numpy 1.11, PIL, `python3-dev` is installed

I'm not sure where / how to get GEOS (`libgeos-dev`?). I think I followed the README and it didn't show any errors, but when trying the first line of [this](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html)

```
$ python3
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get

```
ImportError: libgeos-3.3.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It is in

```
$ locate libgeos-3.3.3.so
/home/math/Downloads/basemap-1.0.7/geos-3.3.3/src/.libs/libgeos-3.3.3.so
/usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.3.3.so
```

Comment: Isn't the [basemap documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) very helpful in saying how to install it?

Answer (score 22):

In Ubuntu, this works for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
$ pip install --user https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

For completeness, if you know you need a specific version, you can find the download links by hovering over the package/version number that you need [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/releases). For instance, if I need to install v1.1.0, I can use the above, replacing the second line with:

```
$ pip install --user https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.zip
```

Comment: Nice, it worked for me! Just one note: If you are inside a virtual environment, the --user option won't work

Comment: @kitsiosk you installed it on python3?

Comment: @Raj yes, did you encounter any problems?

Comment: For me the last command results in an error during the "Building wheel for basemap (setup.py)" step: `src/_geoslib.c:4:10` complains `Python.h` doesn't exist. Using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `sudo -H apt-get install  python.3.6-dev -y` solved this issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev

sudo pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git  # latest Version from Source
```

Older Version might not be compatible with the matplotlib.

Comment: what is the difference between this and the prev answer?